# Today Production - SQL Date Calculation case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, dynamics-ax-2012, production

I have an issue regarding date calculations.

I have a datetime column called `CreatedLocalTime` date with this format: **`2015-11-15 19:48:50.000`**

I need to retrieve a new column called `Prod_Date` with:

```
if “CreatedLocalTime” between 
    (CreatedLocalTime 7 AM) 
    & (CreatedLocalTime+1 7 AM)
 return CreatedLocalTime date with DD/MM/YYYY format
```

On other words, today production = sum of yesterday from 7 AM till today at 7 AM.

Any help using case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `day 7AM` to `day+1 7AM`, you can try:

```
SELECT CAST(CreatedLocalTime as date) 
...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
    CreatedLocalTime >= DATEADD(hour, 7, CAST(CAST(CreatedLocalTime as date) as datetime)) 
AND 
    CreatedLocalTime  < DATEADD(hour, 31, CAST(CAST(CreatedLocalTime as date) as datetime)) 
...
```

For `previous day 7AM` to `day 7AM`, replace 7 by -14 and 31 by 7.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want somthing along the lines of

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime Datetime 
DECLARE @EndDateTime Datetime 
SET @EndDateTime  = DATEADD(hour, 7,convert(datetime,convert(date,getdate())) )
SET @StartDateTime  = DATEADD(day, -1, @EndDateTime  )

--Print out the variables for demonstration purposes
PRINT '@StartDateTime = '+CONVERT(nchar(19), @StartDateTime,120)
PRINT '@EndDateTime   = '+CONVERT(nchar(19), @EndDateTime,120)

SELECT SUM (Production) AS Prod_Date FROM YourSchema.YourTable WHERE CreatedLocalTime >= @StartDateTime AND CreatedLocalTime < @EndDateTime
```

But you could also look at it as all the times which after you remove 7 hours from them are yesterday

```
SELECT SUM (Production) AS Prod_Date 
FROM YourSchema.YourTable 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(hour, -7, CreatedLocalTime ))) = 1
```

The First version will be more efficient as the query will only have to do the date arithmetic once at the start while the second involved executing DATEDIFF and DATEADD  for every record. This will be slower on large amounts of data.

The Gold plated solution would be to add a computed column to your table

```
ALTER TABLE YourSchema.YourTable ADD EffectiveDate AS CONVERT(date, DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(hour, -7, CreatedLocalTime ))))
```

And then an index on that column

```
CREATE INDEX IX_YourTable_EffectiveDate  ON YourSchema.YourTable (EffectiveDate )
```

So you can write

```
DECLARE @YesterDay date = DATEADD(day,-1, getdate())
SELECT SUM (Production) AS Prod_Date 
FROM YourSchema.YourTable 
WHERE EffectiveDate = @YesterDay
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way..

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN CreatedLocalTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, 7,
                                                            CAST(CAST (CreatedLocalTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                                            AND     DATEADD(HOUR, 31,
                                                            CAST(CAST (CreatedLocalTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
             THEN REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CreatedLocalTime, 103), ' ', '/')
        END AS CreatedLocalTime
```

You can write the else part for this, if needed